# How to remove a package from laravel which has providers?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, package, vanilo

I tried to install [Vanilo E-Commerce](https://vanilo.io/docs/0.5/installation) onto my existing application which clashed with a lot of my migrations thus I want to now remove it.

I tried to run

```
composer remove vanilo/framework
```

Which removed everything but then gives me the error:

```
Class 'Konekt\AppShell\Providers\ModuleServiceProvider' not found
```

Whenever I attempt to do anything. I believe this comes from when you do:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Konekt\Concord\ConcordServiceProvider" --tag=config
```

How can I remove this provider? I cannot find it in my `config/app.php` or anywhere else.

Comment: There some time is cache issue, I personnaly found the answer in the feed some times ago.
[Laracast](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-properly-remove-package-with-auto-discover)

Comment: Automatic discovery of Vanilo (and AppShell) Migrations can also be turned off, see: https://konekt.dev/concord/1.6/migrations

Answer (score 2):

You have to delete config/concord.php since that is where Konekt\AppShell\Providers\ModuleServiceProvider is referenced

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear config cache:

`php artisan config:cache` (clears and caches it again, you can also use clear if I remember it correctly)

You can also try to clear the application cache:

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

Comment: When I run this command, I get that error (`Class 'Konekt\AppShell\Providers\ModuleServiceProvider' not found`)

Comment: Run "composer dump-autoload". "composer clear-cache" and "composer update" You mentioned you can't find it but just to be sure. Have you tried to search for "Konekt\AppShell\Providers\ModuleServiceProvider" through your project?